# Recursion method is invoked even after loop condition is met

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, tail-recursion, array-algorithms

```
public int removeMin(Integer[] arr, int count) {
    Integer[] tempArr = new Integer[arr.length -1];
    
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i<arr.length; i++) {
        tempArr[index] = arr[i] - arr[0];
        index++;
    }
    count = count+1;
    if (tempArr.length == 0){
        return count;
    }else{
        removeMin(tempArr, count);
    }
    return count;
}
```

I want the function to return count as 4  when `tempArr.length == 0`.

Input parameters:

```
Integer[] arr = {2,5,8,11};
int count = 0;
```

I am expecting it to return 4 but it's returning 1.

Comment: You need `return removeMin(tempArr, count);` so you can pass on the results of the recursive calls.  The final `return` will never be reached.

Comment: You can add _index_ to the _for-loop_ variables, _for (int i = 1, index = 0; i<arr.length; i++, index++)_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your `conditional` and your `returns` as follows.

```
if (tempArr.length != 0){
   return removeMin(tempArr, count);
}
return count;
```

Here's the complete code.

```
public static  int removeMin(int[] arr, int count) {
     int[] tempArr = new int[arr.length -1];
     
     int index = 0;
     for (int i = 1; i<arr.length; i++) {
         tempArr[index] = arr[i] - arr[0];
         index++;
     }
     count = count+1;
     if (tempArr.length != 0){
         return removeMin(tempArr, count);
     }
     return count;
 }
```

But isn't count always going to be equal to the array size. So what are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks @WJS, I did not knew to use return statement for recursion method calls.

Comment: It's just a part of the code , 
Question : there parcel points and each  point has some  parcels to be picked. And every day an equal number of parcels has to be picked from all the points by the van . So in how many  minimum days all the parcels will be collected.
Point -> [7, 2, 3, 9, 7, 5]  O/P -> 5

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I am expecting it to return 4 but it's returning 1."*

You'll need to return the *return-value* of the recursive call.

```java
if (tempArr.length == 0){
    return count;
}else{
    return removeMin(tempArr, count);
}
```